# Send a SMS for every Android notification (goal: get notifications on Garmin Edge 1000)

Tags: sms, notifications

I am wondering if there is a way, or an app, to send a SMS for every notification the Android phone is getting.

My goal is to try to find a way to send all the Android notifications to my Garmin Edge 1000 device. That device does receive SMS and Phone notifications, but nothing else.

So I was wondering if some feature or app could do that for me. It could send an actual SMS, or it could create a SMS event without actually sending one (not sure if possible).

Any ideas?

Comment: I was about to write an answer using IFTTT but apparently it can't capture notifications. Only send out notifications as reaction to another trigger. I think it is possible with tasker but I'm not sure. Maybe there is a way around it. IFTTT (and tasker also) can definitely send SMS on certain triggers though.

Comment: If someone can answer the question in the following link, it can answer your question. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105769/trigger-actions-on-notification-received-with-ifttt

Comment: Thanks guys, but IFTTT is limited, so I found that I could do exactly that with Tasker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the best way I found to do that for any kind of events that can occurs on the Android phone is by using the Tasker application.

That way, I can choose what notifications will be sent as a SMS, and then the Garmin device will be promptly notified.

Comment: That's great, but could you add the steps to to do that on Tasker (or at least explain a little bit what we need to create/use)? Not all readers are proficient in using Tasker though.

Comment: @AndrewT. sure, you have to create a "Notifications Events" profile. Then you can select all the applications by leaving the first field empty, or select an application for which you want to catch the notifications. Then you can filter the notification events by defining a title and a particular matching syntax. Once your event is created, then create a "Send SMS" action where to send the SMS. Once this is in placce, the mobile will forward the notications events as SMS message that it will then receive, and then Garmin Connect will catch these and forward to the Garmin device.