# Trigger actions on notification received with IFTTT

Tags: notifications, automation

IFTTT has a notifications channel but unfortunately it does not contain any triggers.

Is there any other way to perform an action when a notification is received?
Is there any IFTTT service that can capture notifications and send them to IFTTT?
**How can I use an incoming notification as trigger in IFTTT?**

I don't see any reason why IFTTT can't be one of those notification manager applications.

Comment: This same issue was addressed earlier today in another question, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105758/send-a-sms-for-every-android-notification-goal-get-notifications-on-garmin-edg

Comment: Thomas Martin, Yes I know that. That question was the reason for asking this question. The questions are different but a solution for this question would mean a solution for the other question.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Android Device IFTTT service:

> https://ifttt.com/android_device

It has "Notification received from specific app" trigger where you can filter the Notification by app name and notification keyword.

Please beware that the keyword must be a whole word. Trigger won't be fired if you filter "receive" and the notification is "sms received". You must use "received" as a keyword to catch that notification.

The service also has "Notification received" trigger, that fires for all android notifications.

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Likewise, I am in a similar situation although with the subscription method now implemented in IFTTT leaving free subscribers with only two steps IFTTT has now been left as purely a set of connectors. There is another app - Automate - that I now use to handle most steps in any workflow, however it can push a notification to IFTTT with relevant values and content assigned to variables, expose IFTTT's internal services and deliver into them (or receive from them). It is quite an in-depth app with capabilities far beyond IFTTT but for someone with little coding background it enables within a few steps for the relevant values (assigned to Automate's individual flow's variables) to trigger IFTTT and use IFTTT's connectors to deliver the payload to any of it's connectors.

For instance, I'm using it at the moment to wait for an URL to be shared to a specific flow within Automate through android's share mechanism to the particular Automate 'Fiber' (Automate's terminology for flow), strip the title, media and text into separate entities, and deliver them concurrently as a notification trigger, then via IFTTT's MyCloud Home connectivity to be stored on my device / account. This could also work the other way round as google assistant can pass messages through IFTTT which Automate can pick up, do the heavy lifting and ultimately pass back to IFTTT's connectors to complete.

So, to cut a long story short - the detour is via Automate which has access to all android system services and is far more complex and capable than IFTTT, though simple enough to use some of it's capabilities as a bridge where IFTTT isn't
capable enough at all. It could all be done in Automate, however there would be a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Android notification channel in IFTTT ([If This Then That](http://ifttt.com)) can only *be triggered*, not *be a trigger*. I don't know of a way to use Android notifications to trigger IFTTT. You might want to expand on your question so we can see what you're trying to achieve- maybe there are other ways to go about it.

Comment: "maybe there are other ways to go about it" using IFTTT is exactly my question. The linked question provides an example implementation. How would you like me to expand my question? The only thing I would like to do is use an incoming notification as trigger in IFTTT. Even if it has to take a detour.